# How to scrape tables from a site with bs4?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to code a scraper that scrapes me informations about a product on a site.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = "https://stockx.com/de-de/air-jordan-1-retro-high-dark-mocha"

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Mobile Safari/537.36"
}


r = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
table = soup.find("table", {"class": "latest-sales table table-striped table-condensed "})
rows = table.find_all("tr")
print(rows)
```

So right now im trying to get the table thats on the site but i get an "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'". What could the problem be?

Comment: That table content is loaded dynamically with JS. You can use [selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=scrape%20table%20selenium%20%5bpython%5d) to scrape it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't just look at the surface

You should learn `F12` -> `Network` ->  `F5` -> `get ApiUrl`.

There are a lot of ApiUrls behind this page, I only find what you need, and research the rest by myself.

This is just a simple example.

```
import requests

# my country = Tw
# url = 'https://stockx.com/api/products/f7dcb00f-d0a0-4d47-b419-5022b1b84411/activity?state=480&currency=USD&limit=10&page=1&sort=createdAt&order=DESC&country=TW'

url = 'https://stockx.com/api/products/f7dcb00f-d0a0-4d47-b419-5022b1b84411/activity?state=480&currency=USD&limit=10&page=1&sort=createdAt&order=DESC&country=??'
res = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers).json()
print(res)
for i in res['ProductActivity']:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Im not that familiar with API's, i'll need to get more i depth with it first

Comment: Your question is just to get the content of the form, this `ApiUrl` can get the information you want, and you need to find the rest of the information in `F12`.

Comment: If you want to get information on the Internet, learn to see `F12` to get ApiUrl is necessary, now ApiUrl is common.

Comment: If you insist on not learning, then use `Selenium` to get the data. Only slow.